# how to use AUMatrixMixer

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

i know the AUMatrixMixer is what i need. "A unit that mixes an arbitrary number of inputs to an arbitrary number of outputs."

i found some info here:
http://coreaudio-audiounits.blogspot.ca/2013/04/aumatrixmixer-simplified.html
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html

but the documentation on how to implement it is non existing. how would i set it up, how would i route a specific input to the mixer to a specific output; i.e. how to set up the matrix.

Comment: The only Apple documentation for several audio units is the comments in the header files.  Look there first.

Answer (score 5):

There is a posting on the coreaudio-api list that might help (http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2008/Apr/msg00169.html):

> The matrix mixer allows you to connect any number of input and ouput
>   elements with any number of channels each. You need to make sure you
>   set the stream formats of the inputs and outputs so that the channel
>   numbers are correct. Each input and output channel is numbered
>   sequentially across all elements. So if you were to connect one stereo
>   inputs, one mono input, and another stereo input, the channels in the
>   mixer would be numbered as follows: stereo: 0 1 mono: 2 stereo: 3 4
>   Outputs are numbered in a similar fashion.
>
> The channel numbers are what you use to set gains in the matrix. The
>   matrix has 4 gain controls that can affect any particular route from
>   input to output:
>
> master gain (global scope) - affects the gain of all outputs
>
> input channel gain (input scope) - affects the gain of a particular
>   input channel
>
> output channel gain (output scope) - affects the gain of a particular
>   output channel
>
> crosspoint gain (global scope) - controls the gain of a single input
>   channel going to a single output channel. You make connections from
>   inputs to outputs by setting crosspoint gains to nonzero values.
>
> When setting crosspoint gain parameters, the element number is used
>   differently from other audio units. Crosspoints are set using an
>   element number that is constructed from both the input and the output
>   channel numbers as follows:
>
> element_number = (input_channel << 16) | output_channel
>
> Master gain has element number 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: So essentially to set the volume of a stereo input channel, I will actually need to set the volume of 2 elements?

Comment: To hear something @olynoise on the mxmx, you must enable the buses, set the channel volumes, set the master volume, and set the cross channel mix levels. What a pain. I've gotten the Mac MatrixMixerTest to work on iOS - I'll post it on github at some point.

Comment: @Matt H, Your little note here in the comments is actually extremely helpful. A quick "bullet point" summary like that is what I can almost never find with CoreAudio projects. Thank you!